# How to set spark.sql.pivotMaxValues in python?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Maybe this question is strongly related to [How to set pivotMaxValues in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944612/how-to-set-pivotmaxvalues-in-pyspark). But I haven't find any clear answer about this.

So, how I change `spark.sql.pivotMaxValues`  in my code or configuration file? Where can I find the configuration file?

Comment: If your are using Spark 2.0+ you can do that `spark.conf.set('spark.sql.pivotMaxValues', u'50000')` where spark is your sparkSession

Comment: This comment also works at the start of a pyspark notebook.